# Transformer Model isn't fitting well on Time Series Data

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, time-series, transformer-model

I have created two models LSTM, LSTM with Self-Attention. Now I am working on to create my first transformer model. I created it for multivariate time series predictions (many-to-one classification model).

I have the hourly varying data i.e., 8 different features (hour, month, temperature, humidity, windspeed, solar radiations concentration etc.) and with them I am trying to predict the time sequence (energy consumption of a building. So my input has the shape `X.shape = (8783, 168, 8)` i.e., 8783 time sequences, each sequence contains 168 hourly entries/vectors and each vector contains 8 features. My output has the shape `Y.shape = (8783,1)` i.e., 8783 sequences each containing 1 output value (i.e., building energy consumption value after every hour).

I took as a model an example from the official keras site. It is created for classification problems, I converted my output to classes  `n_classes = len(np.unique(Y_train))` = 156
`Input shape (X_train) = (8783, 168, 8) Output shape (Y_train) = (8783,1) n_classes = 156` 
In the softmax activation layer, I set the output to `n_classes` but it's not fitting well. Below I attach the model and I would like to know:

I)- Have I done something wrong in the model? Is the model architecture is fine? Are there maybe some other parts of the code I need to change for it to work for my problem?

II)- Also, can a transformer at all work on multivariate problems of my kind (8 features input, 1 feature output) or do transformers only work on univariate problems?

```
def build_transformer_model(input_shape, head_size, num_heads, ff_dim, num_transformer_blocks,
                            mlp_units, dropout=0, mlp_dropout=0):

    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = inputs
    for _ in range(num_transformer_blocks):

        # Normalization and Attention
        x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x)
        x = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
            key_dim=head_size, num_heads=num_heads, dropout=dropout
        )(x, x)
        x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
        res = x + inputs

        # Feed Forward Part
        x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(res)
        x = layers.Conv1D(filters=ff_dim, kernel_size=1, activation="relu")(x)
        x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
        x = layers.Conv1D(filters=inputs.shape[-1], kernel_size=1)(x)
        x = x + res

    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(data_format="channels_first")(x)
    for dim in mlp_units:
        x = layers.Dense(dim, activation="relu")(x)
        x = layers.Dropout(mlp_dropout)(x)
    x = layers.Dense(n_classes, activation="softmax")(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs, x)


model_tr = build_transformer_model(input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), head_size=256,
                                   num_heads=4, ff_dim=4, num_transformer_blocks=4, mlp_units=[128], mlp_dropout=0.4, dropout=0.2)
model_tr.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
    metrics=["sparse_categorical_accuracy"],
)
plot_model(model_tr, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
model_tr.summary()
m_tr_history = model_tr.fit(x=X_train, y=Y_train, validation_split=0.15, batch_size=64, epochs=100, verbose = 1)
model_tr.save('halka_transformer.h5')
```

[No. of epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAned.jpg)

Thanks in advance for this valuable assistance.

Comment: This task sounds more like regression, why are you doing classification? is the building consumption continuous or discrete?

Comment: check manually the outputs fo your model, maybe there is just an issue with the metric... if manually they seem correct, than the problem is how the metric works, otherwise there is a problem on the model

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy, the building consumption is continuous.Yes, it's a regression problem.Could you please help me out how to get this model for a regression output.I think the rest of model architecture would be same and all I need is to replace the SoftMax activation function with relu in the last layer?My output has the shape Y_train.shape = (8783,1) i.e. 8783 sequences each containing 1 output value (i.e., building energy consumption value after every hour).`x=layers.Dense(Y_train.shape[1],activation="relu")(x))` Is this the correct representation of the last dense layer for a regression problem?

Comment: Sure, you also need to use mean squared error loss and remove the accuracy metrics.

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy, I just checked it out and the mean squared error loss is even higher than 1000. I was wondering if you could help me with reviewing my code once? Is is possible to send you the code and data for a review may be through email? I would be grateful